# display flex working with all elements except for <input />

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

I am very confused about the following problem. HTML:

```
<div className="SearchBar">
    <div className="SearchBar-container">
        <input />
        <input />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
SearchBar {
    background-color: #0055ff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
  
  .SearchBar-container {
      display: flex;
  }

  .SearchBar-container input {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: .77rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 40px;
  }
```

If I try ANY other HTML tag like span, div, a  whatever it aligns them in the middle perfectly well. But  elements go straight to the right... I tried display:inline-block earlier but the same problem. Any help is much appreciated!

For the record I want two input fields equally horizontally distributed within a div!

Comment: I don't really get it. What is your actual intention here? What does *input fields equally horizontally distributed within a div* mean? If you can please share a picture or something of what you want to achieve.

Comment: min-width:0 to the input element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add flex:1 to the CSS for the inputs they will get evenly distributed in the flexed row.

I've added color background here so you can see clearly which is what element.

```css
SearchBar {
    background-color: #0055ff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
  
  .SearchBar-container {
      background-color: magenta;
      display: flex;
  }

  .SearchBar-container input {
    background-color: cyan;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: .77rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 40px;
    flex: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="SearchBar">
    <div class="SearchBar-container">
        <input />
        <input />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or `width: 100%;`